# How can I tell debugger to don't stop some critical threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, networking

I have 2 projects in solution: network dll and server exe. I want to somehow debug my server assembly without affecting network engine threads. I am not sure how it can be seperated at all. The only possible solution I know is to create unmanaged CLR host for network engine but I already have my C# network engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that's not possible. According to that blog thats how breakpoints work:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2004/12/28/339756.aspx

> Part 3: Notifying the debugger
>
> [Left-Side] Now that the breakpoint is hit, the CLR needs to suspend all managed threads (so that the process can be inspected) and notify the debugger. The thread that just hit the breakpoint will ping the helper thread to request that the runtime be suspended. It will block itself inside of the SEH filter waiting for the debuggee to be suspended. Once the debuggee is suspended, all threads will remain blocked until the debuggee is resumed. This ensures that threads are not running while the debugger is trying to inspect them!

You could start a separate process for your network engine though. But I guess thats not what you want either.

Comment: What the point to start seperate process for *network* engine to which I will connect via *network*? Thats not what I want...

Comment: Can I create new AppDomain or host CLR process from inside my network engine? Will it help?

Comment: I guess AppDomain won't do you any good either. Running a separate process means you are totally independent. But the overhead is huge - inter process communication and so on. Just mentionend for completeness