# Prevent thread from stopping execution when debugging

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging

I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = new Task(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test: " + DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    });
    t.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread Test: " + DateTime.Now);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Debugger.Break();
    }

    return;
}
```

why does task `t` stops execution when main thread stops? is there a way I can have task `t` continue executing regardless if I place a break point on the main thread?

---

### edit

I don't have `Debugger.Break();` in my real code. I send a ping to a computer every 4 seconds to let the other computer know I am connected. **The problem is that when I start debugging my code, the ping is not send every 4 seconds.** It will be nice if I can keep this program as one program and do not have to create a separate program responsible for sending that ping every 4 seconds.

Comment: No, the debugger stops *all* threads from executing.  You can freeze a thread in the Debug + Windows + Threads debugger window.  In case it needs to be said: don't ship this code to your customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. Thats simply how breakpoints work - all threads are breaked!

For more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21339186/2243584

Comment: I guess you are right. There is now way. I have to hurry meanwhile debugging lol